# Point has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, tk-toolkit

why isn't this code working? I am trying to get the button to call the clickGame function. It is opening the clickGame function in a new window but nothing happens, and I am getting an error.
It works without the button function when I press "enter to play clickGame"

I don't understand what Attribute Error means when I try it with the button function:
I keep getting this error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ejoyc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ejoyc\Desktop\Final Project\FinalProjectTest.py", line 26, in clickGame
    center = Text(Point(10,80), "Click to create a circle")
  File "C:\Users\ejoyc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3095, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'text', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\ejoyc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2286, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Users\ejoyc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2256, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

My code:

```
from graphics import*
from random import randint
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


##
##def getInfo():   # draw button here    
##    clickGame = input("Press <enter> to play clickGame: ")
##    print()

def clickGame():

    win = GraphWin("Circle Game", 800, 800)
    win.setCoords(-100, -100, 100, 100)
    win.setBackground("white")

    center = Text(Point(10,80), "Click to create a circle")   
    center.draw(win)
    win.getMouse() # waits for mousclick to get score



    #i = 50
    score = 0
    for i in range(20):

        p = win.getMouse()
        x = p.getX()
        y = p.getY()   

        color = ("magenta","skyblue","purple","pink", "green", "violet", "cyan")
        color = random.choice(color)

        if color == "magenta":
            score = score + 10

        elif color == "skyblue":
            score = score + 10

        elif color == "purple":
            score = score + 10

        elif color == "pink":
            score = score + 10

        elif color == "green":
            score = score + 10

        elif color == "violet":
            score = score + 10

        elif color == "cyan":
            score = score + 10

        # draw score on screen
        # score overlaps

        points = Text(Point(10,90), "Score: %s" %score) 
        points.draw(win)



        circle = Circle(Point(x, y), randint(10, 40))
        circle.setFill(color)
        circle.draw(win)

def getButton():
    root = Tk()

    root.title("MainMenu")
    # ttk.Button(root, text = "ClickGame", command = clickGame).grid()
    # ttk.Button.pack()
    button1 = Button(root, text = "clickGame", command = clickGame)
    button1.pack()
    root.mainloop()    


def main():

    getButton()

##    getInfo()
##    if clickGame == clickGame:
##        clickGame()   #calls the clickGame
##



main()
```

Comment: We need to have the *full traceback*, not just the last two lines. There is no such line in the code you posted, so it is somewhere else but triggered from your code.

Comment: Also: please fix the indentation here. I can't tell where your functions end. Paste your code, then select all the code lines and use the `{}` button on the toolbar to format that block in one step.

Comment: sorry for confusion. I think I copy and pasted it right this time.

Comment: Where is the actual `clickGame` definition?

Comment: added the clickGame function. Was having some trouble posting all the code on this website. Its all up there now.

Comment: Is `Text()` a name defined in the `graphics` library? Because there’s also one in `tkinter`, and that one expects a tkinter window object as the first argument. But you pass in a `Point()` instance instead. But the `from tkinter import *` line replaces any other `Text` name from `graphics` with the tkinter version.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by replaces with. Everything in the clickGame function is just from regular graphics library. do you have an example of a tkinter with what your talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is written with `graphics.Text` in mind, but is actually calling a `tkinter.Text` object. The latter type expects a tkinter window object as the first argument, and the `Point()` instance you gave it doesn’t quite have the right attributes to be a tkinter window.

The problem is with your imports:

```
from graphics import *
# ...
from tkinter import *
```

The first import includes a `Text` object, but so does the second, and because it runs after the first it’s version wins.

You’d be much better of with explicit imports:

```
from graphics import Circle, GraphWin, Point, Text
from tkinter import Button, Tk
```